# MySQL row_count() function always returning 0

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to show the result of rows affected after update, insert, or delete in mysql. I have put

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE ID='1';

SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

With the `ROW_COUNT` the last statement, but the result show me is 0.

Comment: And one or more rows were actually affected by that `DELETE` command?

Comment: Seems to be ok, are you sure that it deletes something?

Comment: yes, the delete is work, but the row_count() is show 0 and same with insert or update.

Comment: how do you run this code? In console?

Comment: actual I am using phpmyadmin...just run in sql query...

Comment: @user3085204 if you are running in phpmyadmin then obviously it will show you 0.

Comment: @RakeshShetty: You might wish to explain why that is "*obvious*".

Comment: if obviously it will show 0. Any other way to show affected rows?

Comment: It will show 0 because PHP reduces multiqueries to one. You can't have two statements in one query. And in phpMyAdmin, every query is new connection. So fresh connection doesn't know what was in previous one.

Comment: So it mean i cannot show the result of affected rows? No other way can solve this problem?

Comment: @user3085204 can you tell us why your running your query in phpmyadmin ? why you are not creating a script to run that query?

Comment: @user3085204 phpMyAdmin (all versions I have used) shows how many rows were affected.

Comment: @VMai did you mean SELECT ROW_COUNT(); works in phpmyadmin?

Comment: phpMyAdmin does show affected rows by default on top, after query, it probably uses `mysql(i)_affected_rows()` PHP function...

Comment: yes @FlashThunder may be you are right.

Comment: See http://squirrelhosting.co.uk/hosting-blog/concrete5-reset-admin-password/1-row-affected.jpg

Comment: @RakeshShetty No :-) `<some delete statement here`; SELECT ROW_COUNT();` gives me 0. But `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = 7` shows up a message, how many rows were affected.

Comment: `FOUND_ROWS()` does return 20, because there are 20 tables in that database. Has nothing to do with previous query...

Comment: yes excatly @VMai i was saying. OP wants to use SELECT ROW_COUNT(); in phpmyadmin

Comment: mysql(i)_affected_rows()is getting error. Can some one give example to use?

Comment: It is a `PHP` function, you can't use it directly in query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know number of rows affected by delete query in PHPMYADMIN then by running your query it will show you the result see below screenshot :[image]

As @Flash Thunder said PHPmyadmin does not allow multiple queries sent at once

If you want to see the affected rows then you can also write a script using PHP which will exceute you sql query and returns the number of affected rows

Comment: you simply can't do that with that tool

Comment: @user3085204 you can't. You have to run some scripts for that.

Answer (score -2):

Just to be clear.

`phpMyAdmin` is written in `PHP`, and `PHP` does not allow multiple queries sent at once... if you are sending two queries separately, second query is on new connection, so it has no access to previous query information. That's why `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` returns 0.

But by default `phpMyAdmin` returns affected rows count in information after query. It probably uses `mysql(i)_affected_rows()` function.

`FOUND_ROWS()` returns number of tables in database when there was no previous query.

```
mysql> use hunting;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select found_rows();
+--------------+
| found_rows() |
+--------------+
|           24 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show tables;

(...)

24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: PHP can send multiple queries at once.  And even if it couldn't, an application written in PHP (such as phpMyAdmin) could split multiple queries into commands that are sent to the RDBMS separately.

Comment: From PHP site: `The API functions mysqli_query() and mysqli_real_query() do not set a connection flag necessary for activating multi queries in the server. An extra API call is used for multiple statements to reduce the likeliness of accidental SQL injection attacks. An attacker may try to add statements such as ; DROP DATABASE mysql or ; SELECT SLEEP(999). If the attacker succeeds in adding SQL to the statement string but mysqli_multi_query is not used, the server will not execute the second, injected and malicious SQL statement.`

Comment: There is an `mysqli_multi_query()` function, that does simply split string by ";" and sends multiple queries, but it is not the same as writting it in in console and phpMyAdmin doesn't use that, afaik.

Comment: Firstly `mysqli_multi_query()` does not split anything within the (PHP) client: it dispatches the multi-statement to MySQL for *it* to parse and handle as one.  That is *one way* in which PHP can send multiple queries at once (my first point).  Nevertheless, my second point stands: even if PHP did not offer such a facility, there is nothing to prevent a PHP application (such as phpMyAdmin) from splitting the SQL into separate queries and submitting them to the server independently.  Thus your second paragraph is outright wrong.